# How do I size conductors to a three-phase induction motor to account for voltage drop?

Tags: motor, design, induction-motor, voltage, conductors

Suppose I have a 480-volt nominal electrical distribution system, and a 460-volt nominal motor. Assuming +-5% variation in the source, it could get down to 456 VAC. I've seen references to motors being required to operate adequately at +-10% of nominal, so that would be down to 414 VAC. That gives us a worst-case 42 volts drop between the 480 VAC transformer and the motor, at full load.

Am I using the right variation ranges for these purposes? Are there any specs or best practices for how to divide that voltage deviation between the run to the MCC and the run from the MCC to the motor?

Comment: You size conductors based upon current (power, power factor).  You derate for safety, ambient temperature, other current carrying conductors.  You select cable and then figure out voltage drop and if required increase wire size for maximum % voltage drop.

Comment: The supply is 480V and the motor is 460V - they've already assumed 20V would be lost on the way.  Could use buss bars as the conductors.

Answer (score 1):

Check with your local electric utility about the source variation.  Although ±5% is common in North America, I have seen some utilities with wider tolerance on industrial services.  This is not usually considered in the conductor sizing, because the motor nominal voltage is almost always lower than the supply nominal voltage by about 5%.

As far as the drop on the conductors goes, there are most likely requirements or at least recommendations from your local electrical code.  If you're doing wiring at 480 VAC, 3Φ from a motor control center, hopefully you are already familiar with your electrical codes.

Energy conservation codes and rating systems like LEED are also in the game now, since voltage drop on conductors is wasting energy by heating the wire, which also causes more waste if you're air-conditioning the space.

If you're in the US, and follow NEC, have a look at paragraphs 210.19(A) and 215.2(A).  A maximum total 5% drop from the service including both feeder and branch circuit is recommended, with 3% due to the branch circuit alone.

Make sure to use the AC impedances of your wiring method (cable, wire in conduit, etc.) and not just the DC resistance of the copper.  You can find a table of impedances at power line frequency to make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use a 460 VAC transformer for a 460 VAC motor or a 480 VAC transformer for a 480 VAC motor.

If you use resistors or inductors to acheive a voltage drop of 20 VAC, it would work only at a certain current. But the current drawn by the motor depends on mechanical load to the motor. Starting the motor draws a very high current for a short time.

Comment: By ANSI/NEMA standards in the US, standard motors  rated at 460V nominal are designed to operate on systems with standard 480V nominal distribution voltage .  The same situation occurs at other voltages: 208 V system/200 V motor, 240 V system/230 V motor, 600 V system/575 V motor, 2400 V system/2300 V motor and 4160V system/4000 V motor.  There are historical reasons for this compromise having to do with regional variations in electric utility standards.